# Relationship between Kronecker's Approximation Thm and Weyl's Equidistribution Thm?

Tags: calculus, probability, number-theory, reference-request

According to Prof. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem), the Equidistribution Theorem was proved by Weyl in 1910 and independently by two others around the same time.

The theorem states that for $\alpha$ irrational, the sequence $\alpha, 2\alpha, 3\alpha,..., etc.  \pmod 1$ is uniformly distributed on the unit interval.

At Wolfram's [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html), a similar theorem is attributed to Kronecker, namely that for any irrational number $\alpha$, the sequence $\{n \alpha \}$ is dense in the unit interval, i.e., one can find a $\{k \alpha\}$ arbitrarily close to any real number b with $0 \leq b \leq 1 $. This is styled the Kronecker Approximation Theorem. Kronecker died in 1891. Note: $\{n\alpha\}$ is the fractional part of $n\alpha $.

I haven't seen a proof of Kronecker's theorem, but I have seen a proof of Weyl's Theorem. Naively (as usual), it appears the two ideas can be used interchangeably in some contexts. Even more naively, it seems there is a strong theoretical relationship between the two.

Can someone offer a thumbnail sketch of the salient differences/similarities of the two ideas (or a good reference for same)? Knowing no better, I would say Weyl owed a considerable debt to Kronecker.

Thank you.

Comment: Weyl's theorem is much stronger and implies Kronecker's theorem, which is much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kronecker is about sets, Weyl is about sequences.

If the sequence $u_1,u_2,\dots$ of elements of $[0,1)$ is uniformly distributed, then the underlying set $\lbrace\,u_1,u_2,\dots\,\rbrace$ is dense in $[0,1)$.

If a countable subset $S$ of $[0,1)$ is dense in $[0,1)$, then (by a theorem of Erdos) it can be ordered so as to be a uniformly distributed sequence - but it can also be ordered so as not to be uniformly distributed.

I have a feeling I've written this out on this site before.

EDIT: found it: [When is a sequence $(x_n) \subset [0,1]$ dense in $[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73810/when-is-a-sequence-x-n-subset-0-1-dense-in-0-1/74189#74189) Not exactly the same as the current question, but there is some overlap.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at the other answer as well.